# Save and restore data with command line

Tags: command-line, password

I will zip a file with a password. Then, I will write a script and ask:

```
if (have the password saved) {
   unzip file
} else {
    ask password
    save password
    unzip file
}
```

I want the user write only one time password in that computer. So what is the best program to save and restore a data. Use a file is too obvious, it will be a little more secure.

Answer (score 1):

My AppleScript-fu isn't up to the task of providing you with the necessary code, but I think you're most likely to find the solution by [leveraging the Keychain.](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/170/usable-keychain-scripting)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to have the user enter a password once, and store the input in a variable that can be reused later on in your script. You can do that like this:

```
# Let the user enter a password and store it in a variable called `$passw`
read -p "Password: " passw
# After that, you can use the variable `$passw`
echo "$passw"
# Delete the password variable at the end
unset passw
```

If you don’t want to echo the password as the user types it, you can use:

```
# Let the user enter a password and store it in a variable called `$passw`
echo "Password:"
stty -echo
read passw
stty echo
# After that, you can use the variable `$passw`
echo "$passw"
# Delete the password variable at the end
unset passw
```